# Replace sets of rows in a data.table with a single row

Tags: r, replace, data.table

I have the following data.table

```
 DT<- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
            place = c("a","b","c","d","a","b","d","e"),
            seq = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4))
 setkey(DT,id)
```

The data.table is ordered by id and seq:

```
setorder(DT,id,seq)
```

For every id, I want to look for the sequence b,c,d and if there is such a thing, I want to replace the rows with b and c with a single row, let's say z (keeping the data of the other columns like in the row with the a).

So in this case the new data.table should be

```
DT.tobe<- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                     place = c("a","z","d","a","b","d","e"),
                     seq = c(1,2,4,1,2,3,4))
> DT.tobe
   id place seq
1:  1     a   1
2:  1     z   2
3:  1     d   4
4:  2     a   1
5:  2     b   2
6:  2     d   3
7:  2     e   4
```

I have to say that I have no idea what to try... I could accept answers with data.frame solutions too!

Comment: Why the row having `b` for `id = 2` is not replaced with `z`?

Comment: @MKR because there's no `c`

Comment: `seq` retains the value formerly associated with `b`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico yes, all the other columns retain the values previously associated with b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = setkey(DT[, {
  w = setDT(shift(place, 0:2, type="lead"))[.("b","c","d"), on=.(V1,V2,V3), which=TRUE, nomatch=0]
  if (length(w)){
    w2 = c(w, w + 1L)
    rbind(
      .SD[-w2],
      copy(.SD[w])[, place := "z"]  
    )
  } else .SD
}, by=id], id, seq)
```

which gives

```
   id place seq
1:  1     a   1
2:  1     z   2
3:  1     d   4
4:  2     a   1
5:  2     b   2
6:  2     d   3
7:  2     e   4
```

Positions w are found using a join against the sequence b, c, d. From there, we identify which rows to drop (w plus the one after it); which rows to keep (w); and what to modify in them (place := "z").

There are too many different directions in which this might be generalized, so probably better to just post a new question if a more complicated case comes up.

Comment: The `shift` function was a gold tool!

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be to group by `id` and evaluate condition/flag where `place == "b"` and `place == "c"` are greater than `0` (meaning both b & c available for a `id`). This flag(say `ReplB` decides if `b` will be replaced with `z` for that `id`. Also, the same flag (`ReplB`) is used to filter out rows with `place == "c"` for a `id`.

```
library(data.table)

DT<- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                place = c("a","b","c","d","a","b","d","e"),
                seq = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4))
setkey(DT,id) 

setorder(DT,id,seq)

DT[,ReplB := sum(place == "b") > 0 & sum(place == "c") >0 ,by=id][
  !(ReplB & place == "c"),.(id, place = ifelse(place=="b" & ReplB,"z",place),seq)]
```

**Updated:** For condition to check `place` (i.e. `a-b-c-d-e`) are in sequence.

Approach :=> Get the position of each place from `letters` and difference of position should be `1` to ensure places are in sequence.

```
DT[,ReplB := all(diff(mapply(function(x)which(letters==x),place)) == 1),by=id][
  !(ReplB & place == "c"),.(id, place = ifelse(place=="b" & ReplB,"z",place),seq)]
#    id place seq
# 1:  1     a   1
# 2:  1     z   2
# 3:  1     d   4
# 4:  2     a   1
# 5:  2     b   2
# 6:  2     d   3
# 7:  2     e   4
```

Comment: Thanks @MKR for your answer, but this way, I think that the sequence requirement is not checked. For example if the sequence was a-c-b-d, the replacement would still take place, but we would like it to take place only when a-b-c-d!

Comment: @User800701 I'm sorry the order of sequence was not very clearly mention in question. But the base solution will still be same. Now, question will be if sequence is `a-b-c-d-e-f` then what will you like to do?

Comment: in case of a sequence `a-b-c-d-e-f` I would like to have `a-z-d-e-f`

Comment: @User800701 Updated solution to consider sequential condition. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks @MKR, this works! I will accept the answer, but do you think it's possible to generalize the solution when the required sequence is not an exact alphabetical order? For instance, m-p-j? Or it could be the case of having more complex labels, like place a - place b - place c...

Comment: @User800701 Absolutely, that is possible. All you need to do is write a function to replace `all(diff(mapply(function(x)which(letters==x),place)) == 1)` which will determine if `ReplB` is `TRUE/FALSE`